# AWS NAT Gateway - See the content

Tags: amazon-web-services, gateway, nat, billing, aws-nat-gateway

First, I saw in the billing section how much I pay for NAT Gateway, I need to understand exactly what I'm paying for, I suspect that the git checkout (we use GitHub) from our instances takes the most of the cost, but I need some way to prove / see exactly the traffic I pay for, is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: May be helpful: http://kamalzerta.com/how-to-analyze-and-reduce-the-cost-of-aws-nat-gateway/. VPC Flow Log analysis will help you understand traffic volumes by source/dest (but not the content, for which you might investigate [traffic mirroring](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-traffic-mirroring/)).

Comment: You also pay for just having NAT running. You do not need to use it for any internet access. As long as you have NAT, you pay for it.

Comment: You pay fixed rate for using it on per hour rate and the rates depends on the region. Other charges are of data in/out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAT gateway does not publish any information about how much data is processed by source/destination. You can deduce it by searching VPC flow logs. [This documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-find-traffic-sources-nat-gateway/) may be useful.